# How to Release AudioContext in Jasmine Tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, audiocontext

I've got an Angular service that sets up an audioContext.  Jasmine is creating a new service for each test, so after 6 tests all tests fail with the error:

`Error: Failed to construct 'AudioContext': The number of hardware contexts provided (6) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (6).`

Is there a way for me to clear the AudioContext between tests?  I've tried `AudioPlayer.context.close()` in an afterEach block, but doesn't seem to be working.

service looks kinda like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('AudioPlayer', function () {

    var self = this;

    self.context = new AudioContext();

    this.doSomething = function () {
       // doing super cool testable stuff here
    }
  })
```

and tests looks kinda like this:

```
describe('AudioPlayer', function () {
  var AudioPlayer;

  beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function ($injector) {
      AudioPlayer = $injector.get('AudioPlayer');
    });
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    AudioPlayer.context.close();
  });

  it('does cool stuff', function () {
    AudioPlayer.doSomething();    
    // unit test
  });

  it('does other cool stuff', function () {
    AudioPlayer.doSomething();    
    // unit test
  });

});
```

Thanks for the help!

Here is a jsFiddle illustrating the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/briankeane/cp929can/1/

Comment: you have a `var self = this;` there right?

Comment: also, please add your `afterEach` code with the cleanup part

Comment: ok, done. What next?

Comment: I still don't think that you're showing everything, because `$injector.get('AudioPlayer');` always returns the same static instance of your service, so it's impossible that `new AudioContext();` is called more then once per the code in your question.

Comment: here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/briankeane/cp929can/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a singleton-like context in the tests, then stubbing the constructor with a function that returns that same AudioContext...  here is the final test code:

```
describe('AudioPlayer', function () {
  var AudioPlayer;
  var context = new AudioContext();     // create the AudioContext once

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('myApp');

    inject(function ($injector) {
      spyOn(window, 'AudioContext').and.callFake(function () {
        return context;                // stub the constructor
      });
      AudioPlayer = $injector.get('AudioPlayer');
    });
  });

  for (var i=0;i<7;i++) { 
      it('does cool stuff', function () {
        AudioPlayer.doSomething();  
        expect(true).toBe(true);
        // unit test
      });
  }
});
```

And here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/briankeane/3ctngs1u/

Hopefully this helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

you can just close it.

```
    audioCtx.close();
```

see documentation
[audioContext.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/close)

Comment: This is currently the right answer. I'm not aware if `close()` was available back in '15.

Comment: This is not correct -- in the question I say: "I've tried AudioPlayer.context.close() in an afterEach block, but doesn't seem to be working."  The sample code in the question also contains context.close().  Trying it in a modern browser still produces the same result. Not sure why it's not working like the documentation says it should.

Comment: Why is close() it not working?  Do you get an error?  You can only close it if it is open.  so a test for state === running or state !== closed is required.

Comment: Okay, I see it.  Close releases the resources, but the audioCtx still exist.  so you can do this.    
       if (audioCtx === null || audioCtx.state === 'closed') {
             audioCtx = new AudioContext();
        }
works in my implementation